# Failure to convert JFIF/Jpeg from CardDAV server's response

Tags: c#, jpeg, carddav

I'm using C#'s WebClient to download and image from a CardDav server and when I look at Fiddler the response from the server will contain a jpeg file, I can even preview the response as an image on Fiddler and it looks fine.

I've tried all the c# conventional methods to convert byte arrays to image/bitmap and none of them work, they throw an "invalid argument exception" exception.

FIDDLER response preview:

> Content-Type: image/jpeg
>
> Cache-Control: max-age=32000000, private
>
> Content-Disposition: attachment
>
> Content-Length: 46341
>
> ÿØÿà JFIF      ÿÛ C ÿÛ CÿÀ  œ ² ÿÄ
> ÿÄ µ   } !1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚
> %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ
> ÿÄ µ  w !1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á   #3RðbrÑ
> $4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ   ? ÿ ?ú (  €
> (Ü>~Î¿iïX|9øà=[âŒ5ËK(4}È{¥k¸¯®ÃÃ$É3YÙéú^©ªêw0E2iºN™¨jw¾M•œó êì…ÿ &ý©ièüq{¯jºÁµøo«Ieâ_
> øâË]³ñµäz–½¦Þbøoû1µ©e¹»ðÖ­§é­£Í£^ëË¢6¡·¥ëú^‘š‹Kvíøú
> ®Á¼:f™û,káü¿þ(~Ô><ñ=æƒðÏÂÞ4Ó"ø/¥Úivþ¹Ôõ=w^Ò¼A¯yö+¢^Xj?b:Ô–/­ØCe|šVÛäµµI÷ð«öcý†>3|hý®¼9û2.™¦øOÆÖþ3—C½»ñî­]ø&ÛZÐŠê'Iñ,iot¶wðÂ>Ý¦]Åm©­Œ—\XGx¯fvM¾‰¿¸ô*ý™?fKŸÙãàÏ†¾~Îqi¿ üsñ7Bñ'íà¿|HøÉ¢i%øà8í<;âü>Õ<3â2ø]|CðÅºèþ›sqáýà³ð]íí‘Õ¾ÚéwÊ´\d£Ì›M'¦­ýCk?Äÿ
> ø‡Æ^"¸øÉñ<|ÃÚ7ˆuÙüpøû7ŽnõO é/™l-õýGâÑé»¨øœk~ ¹Ò5]2ïQ“Á^Ò5“EƒW’æ![•Z|Òv²{ëÑ¿.þ›þw_ðUOØ+Ç²'í6“ÿ ÷„-´¿‰vkã
> ø/áŸˆu  xÃú•êé>ðä:®¥¿¾žâK[ˆàžðIu}qò=î©ró]?Dd¤®¿¯ëüÀýý™¿àß¯|Tý›ü¯|cÅ?

---

```
Format: JPEG
46,341 bytes

178w x 156h
1.67 bytes/px
96 dpi
Baseline
Subsample@4:4:4 (non-opt)
APP0 Data (14 bytes)
[JFIF1.1]
Aspect: 1:1
HuffmanTables: 4
```

SOLUTION
It seems like in my WebClient routine I was pushing some necessary headers that caused the image to be returned in a strange encoding, now I'm pushing only "User-Agent" and "Authorization" and the response can be decoded to image perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in my WebClient routine I was pushing some unnecessary headers that caused the image to be returned in a strange encoding, now I'm pushing only "User-Agent" and "Authorization" and the response can be decoded into an image perfectly.